# Using networks in Docker Compose file

Tags: networking, nginx, docker-compose

I'm trying to understand how the containers talk to each other with Docker Compose.

I'm working in a VM with no domain name, so I use IP address:port.

I want a simple Wordpress app using the standard images : `wordpress:php5.6-fpm-alpine`, `mariadb`, `nginx`. Next to that, I want a phpMyAdmin container with its own `docker-compose.yml`, linking to the MariaDB container.

#### short story

I managed to get it to work with `links`.

Then I tried to setup, but I got an error saying they are not on the same network. I know I could probably have gone with  `--link`in command-line, but that's no fun.

So I figured that's what the `networks` directives are for, and I rewrote my `docker-compose.yml`.

Here's the working `docker-compose.yml` for my Wordpress app (only the relevant stuff)

```
services:
    blog:
        (skip)
        networks:
          - maria_net
          - app_net

    db:
        (skip)
        networks:
          - maria_net

    web:
        (skip)
        networks:
         - app_net

networks:
    app_net:
    maria_net:
```

The app exposes port 8080, where nginx is listening.

I need to tell nginx to proxy php requests to the `blog`container where `php-fpm` is listening on port 9000.

The conf files for nginx are pushed in the container's `/etc/nginx/conf.d`.

What it does :

- sets an upstream pointing to port 9000 of the `blog` container (`php-fpm`),
- sets `root` for static files on /var/www/html, which is a volume shared with the `blog`container
- proxies requests on php files to the upstream

sample `nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

```
upstream backend {
    server blog:9000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        (...more fastcgi_param...)
        fastcgi_pass backend;
    }
}
```

With this setup, Docker takes care of making containers on the same net visible to each other under their service name, and when I hit my VM's IP on port 8080, I get to the Wordpress install just fine.

#### phpmyadmin

I now try to connect a phpMyAdmin container to MariaDB.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        networks:
          - maria_net
        environment:
         - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
        restart: always
        ports:
         - 8081:80
        volumes:
         - /sessions
        environment:
          - PMA_HOST='db'
          - PMA_USER=root
          - PMA_PASSWORD=azerty

networks:
    maria_net:
```

phpMyAdmin actually listens on @8081, but it says it can't connect to host `db`.

Which is quite normal, as I found out :

```
user@host $ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                   DRIVER              SCOPE
3fbb92bac6dc        blog_app_net           bridge              local
fa0ef0ee1a64        blog_maria_net         bridge              local
3b4cd3956119        bridge                 bridge              local
820bc4c6c844        host                   host                local
17b010e55091        none                   null                local
79bcc3149270        phpmyadmin_maria_net   bridge              local
```

phpMyAdmin and MariaDB each have their `mariadb_net`...

I RTFM again, and found that from within Docker Compose, you have to specify that you want to connect to an existing network with `external` (the network's actual  name as listed by `docker network ls`):

```
networks:
    maria_net:
      external:
        name: blog_maria_net
```

Now the phpmyadmin and mariadb containers are on the same network :

```
$ docker network inspect blog_maria_net
[
    {
        "Name": "blog_maria_net",
        "Id": "fa0ef0ee1a6479fba0ed60dc01480a5f2200ff1ab37de511f9a2e55caa238bb1",
        "Created": "2017-07-02T13:01:08.473871818+02:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.19.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.19.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "Containers": {
            "1b0241ed5609f541e60f23717d1cfd55ded4a272536ad417c33e57c573ffec72": {
                "Name": "blog_blog_1",
                "EndpointID": "9e4fd814799cce653299f0751af51482e9f40e15d73bc213af9f120bd7d0f143",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "af6a790c667ba6576ebd056f8166a46d8da7cd1d2704a91e45b93d6d7c945e28": {
                "Name": "blog_db_1",
                "EndpointID": "a9e5d3489f8b156385d1c81c34b6b712708715803080f8b75651ba1bc8fdd039",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "ccaf49d12d928a455c50be33e607e731bb1045f2afe9003c4d22a914af604923": {
                "Name": "phpmyadmin_phpmyadmin_1",
                "EndpointID": "8cfc3efa3654040fdaaa4ffa16643cfab838602d9eead3d14d40c0dd8fd45fe8",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "maria_net",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "blog"
        }
    }
]
```

And the mariadb container is aliased `db` as per its service name :

```
$ docker inspect blog_db_1
(...)
"Networks": {
    "blog_maria_net": {
        "IPAMConfig": null,
        "Links": null,
        "Aliases": [
            "af6a790c667b",
            "db"
        ],
        "NetworkID": "fa0ef0ee1a6479fba0ed60dc01480a5f2200ff1ab37de511f9a2e55caa238bb1",
        "EndpointID": "a9e5d3489f8b156385d1c81c34b6b712708715803080f8b75651ba1bc8fdd039",
        "Gateway": "172.19.0.1",
        "IPAddress": "172.19.0.2",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02"
    }
}
```

But phpMyAdmin still can't connect to host db :

```
MySQL a répondu : Documentation

#2005 - Unknown MySQL server host ''db'' (-2)
```

The double quote might be the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was the quote : I set the environment variable for the db with quotes, that are escaped by phpmyadmin, so instead of connecting to host `db` it tries to connect to `'db'` :

```
- PMA_HOST='db'
```

It should be :

```
- PMA_HOST=db
```

That was a pretty lame problem, but the whole thing about networks in Compose isn't too clear, and I hope that finally getting a working conf will help others.